# ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '' -> '' (JavaScript + NPM + Ubuntu server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

Alright, so I've been making a bot for a popular Teamspeak-like program called discord. I'm running the bot on an Ubuntu server, and use NPM install to install various modules.

Currently, the local version of the bot works fine, but on Ubuntu I can't seem to do "sudo npm install urban" (Urban being the only module I'm having problems with - https://www.npmjs.com/package/urban )

The error I get is

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-27-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "urban"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! path /var/www/chatbot/node_modules/urban
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/var/www/chatbot/node_modules/urban' -> '/var/www/chatbot/node_modules/.urban.DELETE'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/chatbot/npm-debug.log
```

When I cd to the node_modules folder and do ls, there isn't even an urban folder I could work with.

I am relatively new to programming, so I'm sorry if I missed anything, I'll gladly add more information if needed. Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: What does `ls /var/www/chatbot/node_modules/urban` give? Also, what's in node-debug.log?

Comment: use yarn if you can

Answer (score 60):

I simply deleted the `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install` again ;)

Comment: "no person, no problem" - Stalin )

Comment: if you used `-g` then you can't do this

Answer (score 23):

I just **deleted** the folder `node_modules/.request.DELETE/` and then ran `npm install` and everything seems to be working properly.

Comment: How did you force delete?

Comment: @MemphisMeng rm -rf FOLDERNAME

Answer (score 13):

You can use `npm ci` to perform a clean install.

Internally, It will wipe out node_modules and install all packages again. But it is faster than `npm install` if you already have your `package.lock.json`

As per the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci),

```
npm ci will be significantly faster when:

There is a package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json file.
The node_modules folder is missing or empty.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because there is a hidden folder with a `.DELETE` extension present in your `node_modules` folder, Just follow these steps,

```
Open Terminal (click Go > Utilities and double-click the Terminal app)
```

Now copy, and paste both lines listed below into Terminal one at a time, and press Return after each line:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

killall Finder
```

Mac will now show all the hidden folders, delete your module folder with `.DELETE` extension and try

```
npm install <packagename>
```

Use `sudo` if errors

```
sudo npm install <package>
```

That's it. You should be able to install.

Comment: you should avoid installing npm packages using sudo, this is indicative of a higher problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case node process was locking the folder. I used

```
lsof | grep DELETE
```

to find this out. So I just stopped `webpack-dev-server` that was running the process and continued with

```
npm install
```

So check what process is locking the file/folder, then decide how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

This happens when there's a conflict between npm and yarn. This can be resolved by doing any of the following;

- Interchange npm install  with yarn add  or vice-versa.
- You can delete the node_modules folder if you're not sure of the package manager the project runs on then run "npm install".

Comment: Agree, I have a similar problem with pnpm too. Only pnpm consumer can use it as a git dependency, npm consumer will throw errors

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue while running

```
ng build --watch
```

but after trying

```
npm install
```

Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Actually there is a file or folder with .DELETE extension in your node_modules folder.

You can force delete the file or folder with .DELETE extension. Or if you are working on your local machine, issue can be fixed by delete the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling the packages by following command

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Deleting the nodes_modules folder made it work immediately after but the error kept coming back. It turned out I had the directory open!! Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the node version worked for me. I was using node 14 and I changed it to node 16.

Changed default node version to 16 using these commands.

```
nvm install 16
nvm use v16
nvm alias default 16
```

Answer (score 0):

remove node_modules and try npm install
after that try npm install your new pack