# I'm getting ENOMPTY error from npm, I try everything but not working it's been 2 hours stuck with this

Tags: node.js, npm

whenever I do `npm install <package>` this error showing up:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/abbrev
npm ERR! dest /app/node_modules/.abbrev-NLFYEagp
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/app/node_modules/abbrev' -> '/app/node_modules/.abbrev-NLFYEagp'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-10-17T01_05_19_194Z-debug.log
```

I have checked the node_modules yes there's abbrev but I don't need abbrev(all package I need doesn't need abbrev either).

I have tried removing the node_modules with `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` again but somehow it's make my project disk increase so big around 400MB from 20MB, and when I check the node_modules again this abbrev coming back and not only abbrev but there's many package I don't really need it's more than 100+ when I count, I don't need those

package.json? there's just 2 package `canvas` and `axios`
I remove the package-lock too but yea still same

I try to ignore that but I can't because if I do npm install the same error showing up ENOMPTY error, plus they're useless and wasting disk

I have tried `npm prune` but same error showing up, I try remove the folder manual from node_modules but it's to many and at the end those package coming back.
isn't like this before. anyone ever experienced this? how to fix this?

info:
npm version: 7.20.3 &
node: 16.6,
I found a few way to fix on stack or any other web and not working

Comment: Actually, [``canvas`` *does* require ``abbrev``](https://npmgraph.js.org/?q=canvas), plus a lot of other dependencies. I'm not sure where the ``ENOTEMPTY`` problem stems from though. Side note: have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528425/enotempty-directory-not-empty-rename-javascript-npm-ubuntu-serve)?

Comment: ohh, but if I install abbrev another ENOMPTY with another package error showing up, if I keep installing it's wasting disk, oh I've seen that and other questions, but nothing work